# How to fix "The Following Resources Failed to Update" in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have a multi-account pipeline using AWS CodePipeline that is failing in the prod account. The pipeline will work in dev and test but fails in prod and the Cloudformation stack gives the error: "The Following Resources Failed to Update:" and lists several Lambda functions. Anyone know how to fix this? I've checked the permissions and compared them to the other accounts and they seem to match. From my understanding the resources are under the control of CF and should be able to be changed via CDK?
The CDK definitions of the Lambda functions seem to match their current configurations in AWS, So I am having trouble understanding why it no longer works.

The resources also were "drifted" and to fix that I deleted the resource from the stack and made sure to include the "DeletionPolicy: "Retain" before deleting. I of course Imported those resources but I am wondering if that could be the source of the issue?

Really racking my brain with this one

Comment: Can you check the cloud formation stacks in prod account ? 

Usually under "events" in the stack, there is a detailed information, why the stack failed.

If you are having main stack with nested stacks, the detailed information is in nested stack.

Comment: Under "events",  the only info that is provides is: "The following resources failed to update: ..." And lists some lambda functions. Is there anyway to tell why a resource fails to update ?

Comment: Yes, klick on that stack, that is having errors.

Under the "resources" you see information to resources. (lambda is a resource)

Under "events" you see information to events. 

The information can be very helpful, like : 



Cannot delete entity, must detach all policies first. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 409; Error Code: DeleteConflict; Request ID: xxx; Proxy: null)

Comment: or sometimes it is more cryptic, like 

Embedded stack :stack/ApiStackNestedStackResourcewas not successfully deleted: The following resource(s) failed to delete: [ExportFunctionServiceRole0CD064F7].

If the problem is in nested stack, then go in that nested stack, and seek there for error.

In the nested stacks the error is more detailed.

What you start the process, you can also monitor the stack "live" (by manually clicking the refresh button top right :)